# Can we use single where clause for multiple query execution in CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

```
    $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
    $this->db->where('seller_id',$loginSession[0]->seller_id);
    $res1=$this->db->delete('crm_seller_cart'); 

    //$this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
    //$this->db->where('seller_id',$loginSession[0]->seller_id);
    $res2=$this->db->delete('crm_customer_recently_viewed');
```

here both `$res1` and `$res2` return 1 but physically row is not deleting for `$res`, is there any issue in the sequence

Comment: "but physically row is not deleting for $res" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $condition=array('product_id' => $product_id,'seller_id'=>$loginSession[0]->seller_id);

    $this->db->delete('crm_seller_cart', $condition);
    $this->db->delete('crm_customer_recently_viewed',$condition);
```

OR

```
$this->db->delete('crm_seller_cart',array('product_id' => $product_id,'seller_id'=>$loginSession[0]->seller_id));
$this->db->delete('crm_customer_recently_viewed',array('product_id' => $product_id,'seller_id'=>$loginSession[0]->seller_id));
```